# ASP.NET MVC - Atributo que escreva em uma View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Preciso escrever um `Attribute` que escreva uma validação de máscara na View. Dado por exemplo um campo de CEP, eu gostaria que ao marcar uma *property* no `Model` com um `[CEP]`, fosse escrito na View o seguinte:

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        {
            $('#MaskedCEP').mask('99999-999');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Coitada da view... :)

Comment: Achei isso, mas me parece uma bala de canhão para um problema que deveria ser mais símples: [Input Masking in MVC 4 using Data Annotation](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/642477/Input-Masking-in-MVC-using-Data-Annotation)

Comment: Se for isso mesmo, eu adiciono como resposta.

Comment: É isto mesmo, mas uma vez tentei usar essa solução e não funcionou de maneira alguma.

Comment: Não sei se ajuda, mas eu uso [meiomask](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/) é só colocar o tipo de mascara no alt do input e fazer uma chamada simples para todos os inputs `$('input[type="text"]').setMask();`

Comment: @LeandroAmorim Não quero código específico algum na View porque as Views são geradas por Scaffold, e isto me daria algum retrabalho.

Answer (score 10):

**Ideia 1:**

Um forma de fazer seria adicionar o atributo `[UIHint("Cep")]` no seu model, e então criar um editor-template com o nome "Cep.cshtml" que renderiza exatamente o que você quer.

**Ideia 2:**

Uma outra forma de fazer isso, seria criar um tipo `Cep` (sem ser um atributo) e então usar esse tipo, criando um editor-template para ele, assim como um model-binder customizado para este tipo.

### Exemplo usando `UIHint`

Atributo herdando do UIHint:

```
public sealed class CepHintAttribute : UIHintAttribute
{
    public CepHintAttribute() : base("Cep") { }
}
```

Editor template, que deve ser colocado na pasta das views em `Shared\EditorTemplates`, com o nome de `Cep.cshtml`:

```
@model object
@{
    var fieldId = this.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty);
    var fieldName = this.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty);
}
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        {
            $('#@fieldId').mask('99999-999');
        }
    });
</script>
<input type="text" name="@fieldName" id="@fieldId" value="@this.Model"/>
```

Classe de modelo da view:

```
public class Endereco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Complemento { get; set; }
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }

    [CepHint]
    public string Cep { get; set; }
}
```

E finalmente na view em que você quiser mostrar o campo, use `EditorFor`:

```
@model ClienteData

@* ... um pouco mais abaixo no arquivo ... *@
@this.Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cep)
@this.Html.EditorFor(m => m.Cep)
@this.Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Cep)
```

Comment: Eu queria agora o exemplo em código.

Comment: Nada mais justo! Vou editar e colocar exemplos para as duas ideias.

Comment: Depois coloco o outro exemplo.

Comment: Por favor, o outro exemplo eu gostaria que ficasse em uma outra resposta. O que eu preciso está mais próximo da ideia 2. A ideia 1 já vou dar +1. Obrigado!