# jQuery Mask Plugin não formata o número corretamente

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou trabalhando num projeto MVC4, a máscara funciona corretamente quando salvo, mas ao retornar os dados do banco o plugin mostra dados incorretos caso o valor terminar em 0.

Exemplo de dado: `99.000,00`, quando vou na View de Editar fica: `990,00`

Eu posso fazer uma gambiarra para arrumar isso, mas como estou utilizando MVC4, gostaria de saber a forma correta de lidar com essa situação.

**View:**

```
    <div class="campo">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValorPadrao)
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ValorPadrao, new { style = "width:400px", @class ="maskMoeda" })
    </div>
```

**Chamada Javascript:**

```
$('.maskMoeda').mask('999.999.999.999.999,00', { reverse: true })
    .css('text-align', 'right');
```

Campo na Model:

```
public decimal? ValorPadrao { get; set; }
```

Comment: Porque não atribui ao `input` o valor sem formatação (double), que no caso seria "99000.00". Acredito que na passagem da máscara ele deve formatar corretamente.

Comment: Não entendi, você pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Não saco bem de .Net, mas não teria como atribuir o valor sem formatação ao input na renderização da página? No caso com "." como separador de decimal e sem "," no separador de milhar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução! Adicionei o **StringFormat**, no **TextBoxFor**:

```
<div class="campo">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValorPadrao)
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ValorPadrao, "{0:F2}", new { style = "width:400px", @class="maskMoeda" })
</div>
```

E adicionei essas duas anotações no **Model**:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0,0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal? ValorUnitario { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Há [uma pergunta minha em que tento colocar essa máscara como um atributo do Model](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9616/asp-net-mvc-atributo-que-escreva-em-uma-view), mas até hoje não cheguei na solução ideal. [Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9617/2999) é a que chega mais perto de resolver o problema da maneira mais performática possível, mas ainda não é 100%. No geral, é uma boa maneira de resolver.

Outra maneira, um pouco mais fácil e simples de fazer (em compensação, uma resposta que pode fazer seu código se tornar repetitivo) é colocando seu código dentro da `@section scripts`, ao final do código da sua View:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.maskMoeda').mask('999.999.999.999.999,00', { reverse: true })
                .css('text-align', 'right');
        });
    </script>
}
```

Detalhe muito importante: **Esta solução não funciona em Partial Views**. Partial Views não admitem `@section`s. Se quiser mesmo usar essa solução, coloque a `@section` na View pai.

Comment: Cigano, eu consegui fazer funcionar sem precisar fazer isso, consegui passar o StringFormat no TextBoxFor, e adicionei uma propriedade no Model. Segunda-feira eu posto aqui a solução, talvez sirva pra sua também.

Comment: @NULL Acho que não. Na minha eu quero escrever um atributo em cima da propriedade no Model (por exemplo, `[CNPJ]`) e o campo em tela já tenha a máscara de validação sem precisar mexer no StringFormat. Mas agradeço ;)